# Postgres 11.9 : Partitioning by tstzrange

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

I need to range partition a table by tstzrange column. Not finding any examples

```
CREATE TABLE schedule_slots
(
    id                     int8        NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('schedule_slots_id_seq'::regclass),
    time_range             tstzrange   NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT schedule_slots_pkey2 PRIMARY KEY (id, time_range)
) partition by range(time_range);
```

Was trying to create a partition as below

```
CREATE TABLE schedule_slots_part1 PARTITION OF schedule_slots
    FOR VALUES FROM tstzrange('2022-10-01 00:00:00-07','2022-10-01 23:59:59-07', '[)') to tstzrange('2023-10-01 00:00:00-07','2023-10-01 23:59:59-07', '[)')
```

with the intention of all rows between 2022-10-1 and 2023-10-1 being writen to this partition. But, partition creation is failing with error as

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "tstzrange"
  Position: 83
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2183)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:308)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:441)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:307)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeCachedSql(PgStatement.java:293)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:270)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:266)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.execute(JDBCStatementImpl.java:327)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.executeStatement(JDBCStatementImpl.java:130)
    ... 12 more
```

**Please let me know how to partition the table based on tstzrange column**

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE schedule_slots_part1 PARTITION OF schedule_slots
    FOR VALUES FROM ('[2022-10-01 00:00:00-07,2022-10-01 23:59:59-07)') to ('[2023-10-01 00:00:00-07,2023-10-01 23:59:59-07)');
```

Is working !!